# Running an if statement inside a querySelectorAll Node List

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I am building a blog post layout which requires some metadata to sit on one side and stay in place as the content scrolls, using `position: sticky`.

This works fine but some types of content stretch to 100% width, so collide with the metadata as they scroll by. I am looking to run an event listener on scroll which compares the position of both and adds a class to the sticky element, giving it `opacity:0` as the other passes over it.

This works fine when there is only one full width (`.fw`) element on the page:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
var a = document.querySelector('.postmeta-sticky').getBoundingClientRect(),
    b = document.querySelector('.fw').getBoundingClientRect();
    if((b.top <= (a.top + a.height)) && ((b.top + b.height) > a.top)) {
        $(".postmeta-wrap").addClass("overlap");
    } else {
        $(".postmeta-wrap").removeClass("overlap");
    }
});
```

However, the post content is created dynamically and there may be more than one `.fw` per page. I am therefore trying to gather all instances using `querySelectorAll` for my second variable, but I cannot get this to work.

I am this far in:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  var a = document.querySelector(".postmeta-sticky").getBoundingClientRect(),
      objects = document.querySelectorAll(".fw");
  objects.forEach(function(object) {
    b = object.getBoundingClientRect();
    if ((b.top <= (a.top + a.height)) && ((b.top + b.height) > a.top)) {
      $(".postmeta-wrap").addClass("overlap");
    } else {
      $(".postmeta-wrap").removeClass("overlap");
    }
  });
});
```

But it just isn't working. Doubtless I have made some obvious error or omission.

First instance only working in situ: https://hba.matmartin.studio/henry-v-donmar-warehouse/

Simplified codepen: https://codepen.io/MMS_/pen/VwQvvpm

With thanks to anyone who can help.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var a = document.querySelector(".sticky-content").getBoundingClientRect(),
      objects = document.querySelectorAll(".fw");
    objects.forEach(function(object) {
      b = object.getBoundingClientRect();
      if ((b.top <= (a.top + a.height)) && ((b.top + b.height) > a.top)) {
        $(".sticky-wrap").addClass("overlap");
      } else {
        $(".sticky-wrap").removeClass("overlap");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.sticky-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.sticky-wrap.overlap {
  opacity: 0;
}

.sticky-content {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 112px;
  padding: 24px 0;
  background: #e9e9e9;
}

.scrolling-content {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.scrolling-element {
  width: 66%;
  height: 160px;
  background: #d56d56;
  margin: 0 0 48px auto;
}

.scrolling-element.fw {
  width: 100%;
  background: #9dc9dc;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.page-head {
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
  background: #F6F6F6;
}

.page-end {
  width: 100%;
  height: 480px;
  background: #383838;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-head"></div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="sticky-wrap">
    <div class="sticky-content">
      <ul>
        <li>This info</li>
        <li>sticks around</li>
        <li>for a bit</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scrolling-content">
    <div class="scrolling-element"></div>
    <div class="scrolling-element fw"></div>
    <div class="scrolling-element"></div>
    <div class="scrolling-element fw"></div>
    <div class="scrolling-element"></div>
    <div class="scrolling-element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="page-end"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js" integrity="sha256-1XMpEtA4eKXNNpXcJ1pmMPs8JV+nwLdEqwiJeCQEkyc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Off topic: Why are you dropping bits of jQuery in what's largely a plain JavaScript code block? It's not needed and confuses things. See https://youmightnotneedjquery.com.

Comment: It's a great question. The answer is because this is the limit of my knowledge and I don't know any better. I am very open to any suggestion for improvement.

Comment: Each time through the loop you're adding or removing the `overlap` class from all the same elements. So the final result will just be from the last iteration of the loop. Maybe you meant `$(object).find(".postmeta-wrap")` so it only changes the class of something in the current `.fw` element?

Comment: ooh – thanks @Barmar. where would i insert this, exactly?

Comment: In place of `$(".postmeta-wrap")`. Don't you understand that that selects *all* elements with the class, not anything related to the iteration?

Comment: I think we're running up against the fact that I don't understand that, as pointed out by @isherwood. I've just updated the codepen as you suggest though, without having the desired effect.

Comment: I think Barmar's onto something. I'll follow up on my comment by pointing out some things that may help: 1) you don't need the document.ready function around your scroll function. They essentially do the same thing here. 2) You're using an ancient version of jQuery. Chances are you can update to v3.x with no issues.

Comment: thanks – both those things adjusted in the codepen now, and as you suspected all is the same. i'm beginning to understand Barmar's point, but if i'm not mistaken, for this edit to work, the targeted element would have to be within the`$object`, right? which it isn't. there is only one instance of the target per page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should achieve the behavior you're looking for. The problem was that the later `.fw` elements in the list were updating the visibility of the meta element.

I changed the loop to a `for...of` format and added a break to stop the loop when it is hidden, and did a bit of refactoring.

Hope this works!

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    var sticky = document.querySelector(".sticky-content");
    var a = sticky.getBoundingClientRect();
    var objects = document.querySelectorAll(".fw");
    for (object of objects) {
      b = object.getBoundingClientRect();
      if ((b.top <= (a.top + a.height)) && ((b.top + b.height) > a.top)) {
        sticky.parentNode.classList.add("overlap");
        break;
      } else {
        sticky.parentNode.classList.remove("overlap");
      }
    }
  });
```